# How can I show object inside array in JSON in handlebars with NodeJs Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Here is the JSON:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59c3edd10e2a6f083e858036"), 
"email" : "aa@aa.com", 
"username" : "aa", 
"password" : "$2a$10$WcUgbqFjsx.0BwkdEyDNP.R84vz1d7faaL8K0ORcIoBOXOAHxCS3.", 
"words" : [
    {
        "Name" : "xyz"
    }
], 
"title" : [

], 
"__v" : NumberInt(0), 
"name" : "obbk"
}
```

Here is my code for displaying data inside `words`

```
{{#users}}
    {{#words}}
        <h3>{{this.Name}}</h3>
    {{/words}}
{{/users}}
```

But it did not work.

so I wonder how to fix this, how to display `Name` inside of `words`, using handlebars as a template in nodejs to get data from an array inside of a JSON in MongoDB database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
{{#users}}
    {{#words}}
        <h3>{{Name}}</h3>
    {{/words}}
{{/users}}
```

Notice, that in an outer loop (through `users`) you already access `words` property without using `this` keyword, so keep up to that logic inside the inner loop (through `words`).